# ¿Un label puede iniciar siendo "invisible" y después volverlo visible?

Tags: c#, .net, aspx

Necesito que un label sea invisible al momento de "abrir" un form de inicio de sesión
Y que si los datos están mal, aparezca diciendo algo así como "Usuario o contraseña incorrectos"

Y es que sé que se utiliza la propiedad Visible = false;, pero no resuelve el problema.

¿O alguna sugerencia para reemplazar eso?

Comment: Muestra el código, sobre todo la parte que pones `Visible = false;`

Comment: Hola Cecilia, bienvenida, me parece que un enfoque sería iniciarlo con texto **""** y en caso de ser necesario, cambiarlo a **"Usuario o contraseña incorrectos"**. 
Ya que eres nueva te invito a que mires [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, obtengas una mejor respuesta, evitar votos negativos y/o que tu pregunta sea eliminada.
Aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primer medalla! 
Cuando respondas al comentario de alguien, escri

Comment: sera visible = true??? tu pregunta es muy confusa.. es asp.net o que?

Comment: Si es simplemente html, sería de agregarle el atributo `hidden`. Ejemplo `<label hidden>Jon Skeet es noob</label>`

Comment: Yo creo que la pregunta es clara, tiene un ASPX (Web Form), con un login el cual tiene un label. El label debe mostrarse si el user o pass son incorrectos. Este cambio lo realiza en el Code Behind manipulando la propiedad `Visible`, seguramente en un postback. El punto es que sin ver el código no hay como saber que está fallando

Answer (score 0):

## Con la propiedad `Visible`

Debes crear tu elemento con los atributos `runat="server"` y un id, por ejemplo:
`<p runat="server" id="error-label">Hubo un error con el formulario</p>`

Entonces en tu código, al momento de cargar la página puedes usar:

```
public void Page_Load(object source, Event Args e)
{
    error-label.Visible = false;
}
```

Y al momento de hacer tus validaciones, si hay un error estableces esa propiedad a `True`

```
public void Validate()
{
    if (TuValidacion)
        error-label.Visible = true;
}
```

## Con la propiedad Style

Si lo anterior no te funcionó, entonces usa estilos de css desde código:
`<p runat="server" id="error-label" style="display:none;">Hubo un error</p>`

Y tu validación modificaría ese estilo, algo como:

```
public void Validate()
{
    if(TuValidacion)
        error-label.style.display = "block" // O el estilo que necesites
}
```